# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entradas - salidas' in 'where clause'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql

necesito hacer una consulta en base a una operación aritmética (resta) entre dos columnas de una tabla, mi código es el siguiente:

```
$articulos = Articulo::where('entradas - salidas', '>', 0)->get();
```

**Esto me arroja un error:**

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entradas - salidas' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `articulos` where `entradas - salidas` > 0 and `articulos`.`deleted_at` is null)

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser debido a que:

- El método **`where`**<sup>1</sup> de forma elemental requiere de al menos 3 parámetros:

  - columna a usar en la comparación
  - Operador (*aquí podemos omitirlo si es un igual*)
  - Valor para la comparación de la columna
- Puedes incluso pasar un array de de condiciones

Sin embargo dado el contexto de tu consulta, esto no parece ajustarse a tus necesidades; por lo que yo *recomendaría* en pensar en el uso del método `whereRaw`<sup>2</sup> para que de esta forma puedas pasar una sentencia `where` en su formato `raw` de la siguiente forma:

```
  $articulos = Articulo::query()
                        ->whereRaw('entradas - salidas > ?', [$valorDinamico])
                        ->get();
```

**Fuentes de consulta**

- <sup>1</sup>[Método `where`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses)
- <sup>2</sup>[Método `whereRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw)

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a intentar con el metodo whereRaw

Comment: @Omar me avisas si resulta o no

Comment: Otra ves muchas gracias, si funcionó, en otras palabras lo que quería era que solo mandara a la vista aquellos artículos cuya existencia o stock sea mayor que cero. Quedó de la siguiente manera:                               
 $articulos = Articulo::query()
                        ->whereRaw('entradas - salidas > 0')
                        ->get();

Comment: @Omar es genial, no olvides leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Omar considera seguir la sintaxis que da el framework, no es una buena idea pasar el valor directo dentro de la query, imagina que eso fuera parte del request, riesgo alto